# About Ordinary differential equation of first order and first degree.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**Q.** Show that the differential equation of the form

$[y+xf(x^2+y^2)]dx+[yf(x^2+y^2)-x]dy=0$

is not exact. Also show that $1/(x^2+y^2)$ is an I.F. of DEs of the given form.

---

Comparing the given DE with $P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0,$ *Pfaffian differential equation* in two variables, it's obvious that

$P(x,y)=y+xf(x^2+y^2)$ and $Q(x,y)=yf(x^2+y^2)-x.$

I know that the *necessary and sufficient condition* of *Pfaffian differential equation* to be exact is:

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}.\tag*{}$

So if $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\ne\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ then *Pfaffian differential equation* is not exact.

In the present question,

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=1+x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-1.$

Here how I can ensure that whether $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ are equal or not, since the form of $f(x^2+y^2)$ is not known.

I'm not quite sure whether it is a correct approach or not or how to approach further... Please suggest...

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that $P$ and $Q$ are functions of two variables, but $f$ is a function of a single variable. So

$$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=1+2xyf^\prime(x^2+y^2) $$

and

$$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=2xyf^\prime(x^2+y^2)-1. $$

Equality would imply that $1=-1$.